# What's the best way to connect two separate generators to a well pump?

Tags: electrical, generator, transfer-switch

I need to have a generator run 240 volts to a well pump, and want it switched off when the generator is started.  I also want a second (back up) generator that can be switched on if/when the main generator doesn't work.  What's the best kind of switch?  And how should it be wired?

Comment: Do you want this to operate autonomously?  Do the generators start themselves?

Comment: Confirm: you want the well pump switched off while the generator is started, to keep the pump from loading the generator until the latter is running stably?

Answer (score 3):

Many generators (especially those for permanent installation) have optional automatic transfer switch assemblies.  If the backup generator is permanently installed, then I'd recommend buying its recommended transfer switch.  Wire it per its instructions.

If you're going to build your own transfer switch, then make sure that it is "break before make" or has some sort of interlock to prevent both generators from connecting to the load at the same time.  Mains should also be isolated from either generator if mains is present on site.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct type of NEMA power plug and socket will do everything you want.  The well gets a plug (and optionally a switch), and the generators and panel service provide a socket.  You have to plug them manually of course, but the system is effective, inexpensive and most important, easy to understand.